# Postfixのインストールでphp-imapが入らない

Tags: php, postfix

お世話になります。
Postfixのインストールを行っているのですが`php-imap`が入りません。
環境

> CentOS 6.6
>   PHP 5.4.41 (cli)

エラーメッセージは出ていますがよくわかりません。
ご教授のほどよろしくお願いします

コマンド

```
[root@**** ~]# yum install php-imap --enablerepo=remi
```

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
>   Setting up Install Process
>   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>    * elrepo: ftp.ne.jp
>    * epel: ftp.kddilabs.jp
>    * remi: remi.kazukioishi.net
>    * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
>    * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
>   203 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
>   Resolving Dependencies
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
>   --> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6 for package: php-imap-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libc-client.so.2007()(64bit) for package: php-imap-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package libc-client.x86_64 0:2007e-11.el6 will be installed
>   ---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
>   --> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6 for package: php-imap-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>   Error: Package: php-imap-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
>              Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
>              Installed: php-common-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
>                  php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.41-1.el6.remi
>              Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
>                  php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
>              Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
>                  php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
>    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: 質問及び回答の書式に問題があります。回答部に途中経過が書かれています。文書のフォーマットについては編集しレビュー中です。回答を質問にマージして解決となったコメントが回答になると思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

すみません
PHPのTypoがわかりません。

```
yum install -y postfix httpd mysql php dovecot dovecot-mysql
```

でインストールしました。

コマンドを実行すると下記のように出力されました。
どのように見ればいいのでしょうか？

```
[root@*** ~]# yum info php-imap --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=remi
```

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security Loading mirror
>   speeds from cached hostfile  * remi: remi.kazukioishi.net Available
>   Packages Name        : php-imap Arch        : x86_64 Version     :
>   5.4.41 Release     : 1.el6.remi Size        : 82 k Repo        : remi Summary     : A module for PHP applications that use IMAP URL        
>   : http://www.php.net/ License     : PHP Description : The php-imap
>   package contains a dynamic shared object (DSO) for
>               : the Apache Web server. When compiled into Apache, the php-imap
>               : module will add IMAP (Internet Message Access Protocol) support to
>               : PHP. IMAP is a protocol for retrieving and uploading e-mail
>               : messages on mail servers. PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting
>               : language. If you need IMAP support for PHP applications, you will
>               : need to install this package and the php package.

Comment: Typo は、Postfix と PHP は直接関係ないので、書き間違えたのかと思った次第です。
remi の php-imap が見えていますので、そのままインストールできませんか？
yum install php-imap --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=remi
  あるいは
yum install php-imap --enablerepo=remi

Comment: yum install php-imap --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=remi 
では下記のようになります。（エラーが減ったようです。）
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-imap-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libc-client.so.2007()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest


 yum install php-imap --enablerepo=remi
ではかわりません

Comment: remi リポジトリが見えるようになっていますので、最初の yum install php-imap --enablerepo=remi で、依存関係にある libc-client も一緒にインストールできると思います。ダメだったら、先に yum install libc-client でインストールしてから、yum install php-imap --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=remi でどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございました
yum install libc-client
を実行してから
yum install php-imap --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=remi
を実行したところうまくいきました。

Answer (score 2):

質問文の Postfix は PHP の Typo でしょうか？
php-imap が remi リポジトリのものが見つからず、CentOS 6 のものをインストールしようとして、既にインストール済みの remi の php と競合しています。

以下のコマンドで remi リポジトリのみ有効にして、php-imap が見つかるでしょうか。

```
yum info php-imap --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=remi
```